# PHP Query in MongoDB doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb

I have been trying to fix this problem since days and I can't really solve it.

I'm trying to use mongo DB for my first time and here's my problem:

```
$id = utf8_encode($_POST['mongo']);
$query=array("id" => $id);
$conn = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$database = $conn->test;
$collection = $database->pages;
$doc = $collection->findOne($query);
```

The `$id` variable is set to 2, but `findOne` doesn't return anything.

If I try for example to change the `id` value in array with 2 `[$query=array("id" => 2);]` the DB returns the document that I need.
It's a mystery ahah.
Can anyone see an error?
Thanks
L

Answer (score 0):

After connect you should be select your document

```
$id = utf8_encode($_POST['mongo']);
$query=array("id" => $id);
$m = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$db = $m->selectDB('yourdocumentname');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'yourcollectionname');


$doc = $collection->findOne($query);
    var_dump($doc);
```